# Need better approach for azure api to process large amount of data

Tags: python, azure, rest, azure-functions, azure-api-management

We have **Azure http triggered function app(f1)** which talks to another **http triggered function app(f2)** that has a prediction algorithm.
Depending upon input request size from function(**f1**), the response time of function(**f2**) increase a lot.
When the response time of function(**f2**) is more, the functions get timed out at 320 seconds.

- Our requirement is to provide prediction algorithm as a
  service(**f2**)
- An orchestration API(**f1**) which will be called by the client and
  based on the clients input request (**f1**) will collect the
  data from database do data-validation and pass the    data to
  (**f2**) for prediction
- After prediction (**f2**) would respond back predicted result to
  (**f1**)
- Once (**f1**) receives the response from (**f2**), (**f1**) would respond
  back to client.

> We are searching for alternative azure approach or solution which will
> reduce the latency of an API and also the condition is to have **f2**
> as a **service**.

Answer (score 0):

If it takes more than 5 minutes in total to validate user input, retrieve additional data, feed it to the model and run the model itself, you might want to look at something different than APIs that return response synchronously.

With these kinds of running times, I would recommend a asynchronous pattern, such as F1 stores all data on a Azure Queue, F2 (Queue triggered) runs the model and stores data in database. Requestor can monitor database for updates. Of F1 takes the most time, than create a F0 that stores the request on a Queue and make F1 queue triggered as well.

Answer (score 0):

As described in [Limits for Http Trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-http-webhook-trigger?tabs=csharp#limits):

> If a function that uses the HTTP trigger doesn't complete within 230 seconds, the Azure Load Balancer will time out and return an HTTP 502 error. The function will continue running but will be unable to return an HTTP response.

So it's not possible to make **f1** and/or **f2** Http Triggered.

---

Alternatives are many, but none can be synchronous (due to limitation above) if:

- Interface to end user is REST API and
- API is served by Http Triggered Azure Function and
- Time needed to serve request is greater than 230 seconds.

---

Assuming:

- Interface to end user is REST API and
- API is served by Http Triggered Azure Function

one async possibility would be like this:
[image: async]

PS: I retained **f1** and **f2**, which do the same as in your design. Though their trigger/output change.

- Http Triggered REST API from **f3** is the entry point for end user to trigger the `job`. Which would post to queue `q1` and return a `job-id` / status-url as response.
- user can query/poll current status/result of job by `job-id` using another Http Trigger API served by **f4**.
- **f1** and **f2** are now triggered by queue trigger
- **f1**, **f2** and **f3** update status for each `job-id` whenever needed into ADLS (which could be anything else like [Redis cache](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/cache/) or [Table Storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/tables/table-storage-overview) etc).
- **f4** need not a separate function, it can be served as a different path/method from **f3**.